# JQuery: Getting a series of checkboxes to validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function, validation

I'm trying to get a group of checkboxes as part of an overall form I created in the admin area of WordPress to validate. Basically, custom fields. Here's what the code looks like:

```
<div><label><input type="checkbox" value="0-2"  name="_ecp_custom_5[]" /> 0-2</label></div>
<div><label><input type="checkbox" value="3-5"  name="_ecp_custom_5[]" /> 3-5</label></div>
<div><label><input type="checkbox" value="6-8"  name="_ecp_custom_5[]" /> 6-8</label></div>
```

and so on.....

So I have this in my JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('[name="_ecp_custom_3"]').attr("required", true);
    $('[name="_ecp_custom_5[]"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

First line for a text field, works great. But the checked one underneath doesn't work at all. If I submit the form without checking a box, the form still publishes and when it comes back, all the fields are now checked even though I didn't check any of them.

Puzzled what to do in regards to that since there's going to be several rules in this validation function.

Comment: Why do names have "_ecp_custom_5[]" values whereas in your code you refer to just "_ecp_custom_5"? They are not the same.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter if I use _ecp_custom_5[] or _ecp_custom_5 without the brackets at the end. No longer get an error when I use _ecp_custom_5[] but the form still publishes even with no fields checked. And when it comes back, all the fields are checked. I'll update the original post.

Comment: @AdamBell Are you using html?

Comment: Also, your jQuery is set to check all the checkboxes, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Jane, I just want to validate that at least one of the checkboxes is checked off. Not check all the boxes. Just validate.

Comment: But your code sets all checkbox inputs with `name=_ecp_custom_5[]` to checked?

Comment: So what should it be? All I want to do is make it required to have the user check at least one of the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html:

> An html element name and id cannot include special characters, such as `[ ]`, and **must** begin with a letter (A-Z), (a-z).

Aside from that, your jQuery references an element with the `name=_ecp_custom_5` and not `name=_ecp_custom_5[]`.  Simply remove the `[]` in your names and your code will work.

### Update

The `$('[name=foo]').prop("checked", true)` sets **all** checkboxes with `name=foo` to checked.  I'm a bit confused about what you are asking at this point, since it seems like you are confused about why your form is submitting all checkbox inputs as checked?

Comment: First off, I'm using PHP as this is a form inside of WordPress to post events.originally, I didn't have the [] in there. If I exclude them, then I get an error that

Comment: First off, I'm using PHP as this is a form inside of WordPress to post events

Originally, I didn't have the [] in there. If I exclude them, the form still publishes even if nothing is checked. I brought it back and the good news is, the form no longer checks off any of those checkboxes but at the same time, it also does not validate. So that's the bad news.

Answer (score 0):

## You want to require that at least one checkbox is checked, right?

You can iterate all inputs with the name attribute value of **"_ecp_custom_5[]"** by using *jQuery.each()*. With that, you can create any flag variable that will be used on any condition.

Please refer to the snippet below if you can't visualize what I am trying to say.

> If you want to require that at least one checkbox is checked, you can use this example as your basis

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnValidate').click(function() {
    var flag = false;

    $.each($('[name="_ecp_custom_5[]"]'), function(index, value) {
      var checkboxStatus = $(this).prop('checked');

      if (checkboxStatus == true) {
        flag = checkboxStatus;
      }
    });

    if (flag == false) {
      alert('No checkbox has been checked')
    } else {
      alert('Success!')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="0-2"  name="_ecp_custom_5[]" /> 0-2
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3-5"  name="_ecp_custom_5[]" /> 3-5
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="6-8"  name="_ecp_custom_5[]" /> 6-8
  </label>
</div>

<button id="btnValidate" style="margin-top: 20px;">Validate</button>
```

### How I did it?

I iterated all inputs with the **name** attribute value of ***"_ecp_custom_5[]"***.

Then I created a boolean variable named *"flag"* (default value is *false*) that is being changed to **true** only if a checkbox from the iteration has the *prop('checked')* value of *true*. If no checkbox has been checked, then the *"flag"* variable's value will remain **false** which will then be checked by my condition.

Comment: Here’s the problem with that. If you look at the original script, it also has a text input field that also has to be required as well. You just have checkboxes and completely ignored the other requirement. How do I add that?

Comment: So I tried your script and yes, I got the prompt that I did not check a box. However, the post still published anyway. This is meant to post to WordPress.